# Create a nice color palette

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I'm trying to create a ComboBox where i can choose a Color (which is used afterwards in drawing lines for a graph chart)

i have played aroung a bit coming to something like this:

```
        int interval = 120;

        for (int red = 0; red < 255; red += interval)
        {
            for (int green = 0; green < 255; green += interval)
            {
                for (int blue = 0; blue < 255; blue += interval)
                {
                    if (red > 150 | blue > 150 | green > 150 ) //to make sure color is not too dark
                    {
                        ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
                        item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)(red), (byte)(green), (byte)(blue)));
                        item.Content = "#FF" + red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2");
                        cmbColors.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

which makes something like this here:

[image]

As you can see i have color pairs and it looks a bit weird, does anybody have a better idea for this? (i use wpf)

Comment: Consider sorting the colors by hue rather than by their RGB value. That way the transition between the colors will be less jarring.

Comment: What looks weird in this?

Comment: What about using the [Extended WPF Toolkit ColorPicker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ColorPicker)?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, asking someone if they are colour blind is not rude as far as I'm aware, but apologies if you thought that it was. Can you see the purple colours in the middle of the green/blue colours? Or the way that yellow 'jumps' to pink, rather than fades gradually? That is what we are talking about.

Comment: @Sheridan My first language is not english may be that is the reason I saw it offensive. NVM. So what op means is just they're mixed up right?

Answer (score 1):

Your request is subjective ("a bit weird" is not an exactly phrased question!) but sorting them by hue looks something like this:

```
    int interval = 120;

    List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
    for (int red = 0; red < 255; red += interval)
    {
        for (int green = 0; green < 255; green += interval)
        {
            for (int blue = 0; blue < 255; blue += interval)
            {
                if (red > 150 | blue > 150 | green > 150 ) //to make sure color is not too dark
                {
                    colors.Add(Color.FromARGB(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)(red), (byte)(green), (byte)(blue));
                }
            }
         }
     }
     var sortedColors = colors.OrderBy(c => c.GetHue())
                              .ThenBy(c => c.GetSaturation())
                              .ThenBy(c => c.GetBrightness());
     foreach (Color c in sortedColors)
     {                        
         ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem {
             Background = new SolidColorBrush(c),
             Content = string.Format("#{0:X8}", c.ToArgb())
         };
         cmbColors.Items.Add(item);
     }
```

If this doesn't look aesthetic enough, try permuting the `GetHue`, `GetSaturation` and `GetBrightness` calls until you're happy.